# Phone interviewer missed scheduled call (twice)

Tags: interviewing, job-search

I was excited to move forward in the round of interviews with a large, reputable company.  The original phone interview was scheduled on a Thursday, the manager/team members missed the interview, and I never received a call.  Now, I understand things happen, I politely emailed the recruiter and they all apologized for the inconvenience and we re-scheduled the interview.  Today, they did not call again!

I might be willing to re-schedule if the reason was legitimate, however if it was simply negligence this might be a 'red flag.'  I'm not sure why the first interview was missed; I just gave benefit of the doubt.  Should I move on?

**Would it be wrong for me to inquire about the reason the interview was missed?**  Again, I do understand things happen - I'm just not sure at this point.

Comment: Things happen. Ask again.

Comment: My friends have had very similar situations with certain companies — its not particularly uncommon for something like this to happen. Also, this is on them, don't feel bad for following up on their lack of communication

Comment: Goldfinger's Rule would seem to apply in this situation: "Once is happenstance, twice is coincidence, three times is enemy action."  By that, I mean it won't kill you to give them one more opportunity to get their act together, but, if they blow it again, you put them on your farthest back burner and Move On With Your Search.

Comment: Why didn't you ask the reason the first time? Maybe the reason was something that you could have corrected, like a wrong phone number, etc.

Comment: I confirmed the phone number when scheduling the interview.  I understand that things happen; it did not seem necessary to ask the first time around.  They were apologetic, so I gave the benefit of the doubt.

Answer (score 11):

Don't overthink this. What do you have to lose by asking for a third appointment?

Best case, it was just bad luck twice in a row, and they would love to talk to you. Worst case, they are disorganized and cannot manage appointments - that should become obvious once you talk to them.

As long as you do not know more, just assume the best and prepare for the worst, as they say. So politely ask for a third call, and if you want to, you can ask what happened and whether there is anything you can do to make it work this time.

That said, you should probably not go out of your way to find a new time for an  interview - after two failed attempts, the other side should accomodate *your* choice of time. Most of all, certainly do not delay acting on other job offers if there are any - the two failed attempts are not a good sign.

Comment: You could also ask for their phone number so that you can call them if you don't hear anything. However, at that point I would probably not be interested anymore.

Comment: I emailed the recruiter!  I suppose it won't hurt to reschedule and see what happens.

Comment: Actually, there *could* be something to lose if the OP has cancelled other plans and is re-arranging the day to accommodate this call that never comes through.  I've had this happen, but actually with recruiters scheduling a follow up call with me and then flaking.

In the case whether it's the client OR the recruiter, such instances could be a red flag.

Comment: @codenoir: Good point. I edited my answer.